# How to stop img from shaking when moving element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transforms

I have flex-box animation going when button is clicked, but when it happens the img shakes a bit (something like 1-2px back and forth) it's ever so slightly but it's noticeable, if you having hard time seeing this let me know i will try to create a video.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/MariusZMM/pen/PLzodX

```css
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #544;
    }
    
    .container {
      position: relative;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-direction: row;
              flex-direction: row;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .item {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .item .cA,
    .item .lI {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .f1 {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
          -ms-flex-positive: 0;
              flex-grow: 0;
    }
    
    .f2 {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          -ms-flex-positive: 1;
              flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    .f2 .btn {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50%;
      height: 70px;
      top: 80%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background: #444;
    }
    
    .img {
      background-image: url("https://davidcrew.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/wallpaper-177057.jpg");
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .f3 {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1.5;
          -ms-flex-positive: 1.5;
              flex-grow: 1.5;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">

  <div class="item f1" style="background: red"></div>

  <div class="item f2 img">
   <button class="btn">
    <div class="sI">Sign In</div>
   </button>
  </div>

  <div class="item f3" style="background: blue"></div>

 </div>
```

Comment: I think the issue is with background-position: fixed; This property have performance issues in Google chrome.

Comment: you might be right, but i have tried on Safari same issue. Firefox does not have this issue.

Comment: By Chrome I mean Web-kit browsers. This might help: https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property/

Removing background-position: fixed; will solve the scrolling issue

Comment: Yep i was reading something similar https://medium.com/vehikl-news/fixed-background-image-performance-issue-6b7d9e2dbc55 will try and post back with results

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by Sree all working great now https://codepen.io/MariusZMM/pen/eXzNKX

But I'm just curious if i use bootstrap it makes padding on left and right side which i can't seem to get rid off. But when i disable Bootstrap all good. It's not an issue, but curious what is causing this ins Bootstrap?

Full version with Bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
    <script rel="preload" src="./js/anime.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="item f1" style="background: red"></div>

        <div class="item f2">
            <div class="img"></div>
            <button class="btn">
                <div class="sI">Sign In</div>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="item f3" style="background: blue"></div>

    </div>

    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d63d3d;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item .cA,
.item .lI {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.img::before {
  background-image: url("https://davidcrew.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/wallpaper-177057.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
  will-change: transform;
}

.f1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
}

.f2 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

.f3 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1.5;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1.5;
          flex-grow: 1.5;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #444;
}
```

JS:

```
var start = anime.timeline({
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  autoplay: false,
  duration: 450
});

start
  .add({
    targets: '.f3',
    flexGrow: '0'
  })
  .add({
    targets: '.f1',
    flexGrow: '1.5'
  });

document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = function() {
  start.play();
  if (start.began) {
    start.reverse();
  }
};
```

Update: adding padding: 0; solved. I just needed to add this in right place which in this case was .container